# What is "proof of defense"?

Tags: black-desert-online

I've been looking at articles about the uses of energy in Black Desert Online, and many of them seem to take their information from the same source, because they all include the exact same list of things that use energy. Namely:

- Story Exchange
- Greetings
- Theft
- Learn from an NPC
- **Proof of Defense**
- World Chat
- Node Management
- Gathering
- Contracting Workers

What the heck is this "proof of defense," and how exactly do I go about spending energy on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settlements in BDO are sometimes attacked by groups of monsters. When you kill them, these monsters drop a Defense Token. These tokens can be turned in to gain contribution points, at an NPC in that settlement. It takes 5 badges and 3 energy to turn them in.